# Gunicorn is getting slow after project start or restart

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I have deployed my django project on "Centos 7" OS with posgresql, nginx and gunicorn. After couple of minutes of project is running or restart, it's getting so slow. But there is no errors in the project or responses. It's for sure not db related issue. One thing to take into considiration that, my project gets quite big load

gunicorn.service is given below:

````
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/myproject
ExecStart=/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/user/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target```

checked network, cpu load, db load. Everything is fine. No idea what is wrong
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change workers number according to cpu cores